# Div expands when input is added

Tags: javascript, html, css

When adding a new input field, the width of the fields block increases each time.
How can I fix it without specifying the width for the fields block?

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var input = '<input type="text">';
  $("#fields").append(input);

}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#fields {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
}

#fields input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fields">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: You realise this never ever stops adding `input`; you should probably add a counter system so that a maximum number of input's are added to the page.

Comment: your infinity problem can be solved by `if($("#fields > input[type=text]").length) < 10) { $("#fields").append(input); }` Technically it would be better to put this `if` qualifier outside of the `setInterval` action but you should be able to tweak this as you need...

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to modify the `width` of `input` you can `flex` the `#fields` container and specify `flex-direction: column;`.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var input = '<input type="text">';
  $("#fields").append(input);

}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#fields {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
}

#fields input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fields">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: block` instead `width: 100%`:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var input = '<input type="text">';
  $("#fields").append(input);

}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#fields {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
}

#fields input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fields">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: But why is the initial field not 100% in OP's code?

Comment: Because of flex display, you can try use flex-direction: column;

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var input = '<input type="text">';
  $("#fields").append("<br>"+input);

}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;  
}

#fields {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;  
  text-align:center;
}



#container{
width:60%;
border:solid 2px green;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
<div id="fields">
  <input type="text">
</div>
</div>
```